OIT + MSAA causes glitches in Metal
I'm trying to implement both OIT (Order Independent Transparency) and MSAA (Multiple Sample Anti-Aliasing) but the rendering is glitchy (see image below).

OIT works normally without MSAA and vice versa. Only the combination of both causes glitches.
OIT is implemented with image blocks following apple's tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/metal_sample_code_library/implementing_order-independent_transparency_with_image_blocks.
I provide a MRE (Minimal Reproductible Example) to reproduce the issue:
OIT+MSAA
Note that you can orbit the camera with a drag gesture.

there has been a similar question here and it all comes down to initializing the imageblock and dispatching proper amount of threads.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78179886/metal-image-blocks-and-msaa

I made it work by updating the function that initialize the data block.
FROM:
kernel void initializeTransparentFragments(imageblock<TransparentFragment, imageblock_layout_explicit> blockData, ushort2 localThreadID [[ thread_position_in_threadgroup ]]) {
threadgroup_imageblock TransparentFragment* values = blockData.data(localThreadID);
    for (short i = 0; i < layerCount; ++i) {
        values->colors[i] = 0;
        values->depths[i] = INFINITY;
    }
}

TO:
kernel void initializeTransparentFragments(imageblock<TransparentFragment, imageblock_layout_explicit> blockData, ushort2 localThreadID [[ thread_position_in_threadgroup ]]) {
    for (short k = 0; k < sampleCount; ++k) {
        threadgroup_imageblock TransparentFragment* values = blockData.data(localThreadID, k, imageblock_data_rate::sample);
        for (short i = 0; i < layerCount; ++i) {
            values->colors[i] = 0;
            values->depths[i] = INFINITY;
        }
    }
}

Many thanks to Spo1ler who spotted the issue!
